# Laravel injections and services

Tags: laravel

I have two services with business logic: ItemService and BagService. And each service have writeOff method. And i can't figure out how to implement logic when  ItemService writeOff method needs to use BagService service writeoff method and BagService writeoff method need to use ItemService writeoff method. Is it even possible to have this logic with services and injections? Because now i get infinite loop.

```
class EstoreItemService
{
    protected $bagService;

    public function __construct(BagService $bagService)
    {
        $this->bagService = $bagService;
        // ... other injections
    }

    public function writeOff(int $id)
    {
        //find item and its bag (with bag items) by given item id
        $item = Item::with('bag.items')->find($id);

        $item->delete();
        // ... item write off logic, like notifications, summary updates and other

        //if item bag is empty write off bag
        if ($item->bag->items->count() == 0) {
            $this->bagService->writeOff($item->bag);
        }

        return true;
    }

    // ... other methods
}
```

---

```
class EstoreItemService
{
    protected $itemService;

    public function __construct(ItemService $itemService)
    {
        $this->itemService = $itemService;
        // ... other injections
    }

    public function writeOff(int $id)
    {
        //find bag and its items by given bag id
        $bag = Bag::with('items')->find($id);

        $bag->delete();
        // ... bag write off logic, like notifications, summary updates and other

        //write off all item in bag
        foreach ($bag->items as $item) {
            $this->itemService->writeOff($item->id);
        }

        return true;
    }

    // ... other methods
}
```

Comment: You have circular dependencies. You need to reconsider your current architecture to resolve this. Maybe extract the `writeOff` function into a service of its own which is injected into your `ItemService` and `BagService`. It might also be that `ItemService` and `BagService` can and should be combined into a single service with a `writeOff` method.

Answer (score 0):

[Peppermintology](https://stackoverflow.com/users/281278/peppermintology) offered 2 ways and both has problems:

> Maybe extract the writeOff function into a service of its own which is
> injected into your ItemService and BagService

it works only on situations like this, when you need to use "writeoff" on both services, but when you need to use some method like "updateProductPrice" (which is only used in product) then you should have this method in "ProductSercice"? or in third service? I think it will be confusion when to use third service and when to use main Product or Bag service.

> It might also be that ItemService and BagService can and should be
> combined into a single service with a writeOff method

I think it is more clear solution to split "resources" in separate services (like ProductService, BagService), combined service will have a lot of code in single file and I think it is not clear solution.

I am also interested if there is any other solutions or how to solve problems of offered solutions.